# How can i set up my own store?

Tags: ios, xcode, itunes

I am working on set up my own store. So when somebody wants download my app he will connect my vpn  and download my app from there. How can i do that? Do you have an idea?

Comment: Frankly since you are tagging this ios - you can't, the platform is locked down and all the devices that would use *your* store would have to be jailbroken. This question is unbelievably broad in scope and should probably be closed.

Comment: The only way someone could use 'you' as an app store is if they've jailbroken their device, which voids their warranty. If you want to play on an iDevice, you'll be playing by Apple's rules, or not at all.

Comment: Why on earth did this get an upvote????

Comment: @iandotkelly   have you ever heard vpn demand?

Comment: Yes, and?  Its a big leap from VPN to having an App Store.  The device will not accept applications that are not correctly provisioned for it - either via the official app-store or via an enterprise deployment.  If this were not the case with a platform that is 4 years old and has hundreds of millions of units out there, and billions of apps downloaded - someone would be doing this already.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. All iOs applications need to be downloaded from the official Apple iTunes store.